# Careers site search by country "uk" is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Searching jobs by country (["UK"](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&location=uk)) used to work a few days ago. Now it only returns two jobs or so. Searching by other things, e.g. ["London"](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&location=london) gives far more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for this, we've got a bit of spurious geography data getting in there. Try it again?

Comment: Looks fixed to me.